# Certbot renew - Certbot failed to authenticate some domains

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy, certbot

my certificates are beginning to expire, before I automate my certificate renewal, I wanted to renew it once manually. But sadly that doesn't work.

FYI I use a NGINX reverse proxy and manage my certificates with certbot.

certbot renew output:

```
Renewing an existing certificate for example.com and sub.example.com

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: sub.example.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: "IP-ADRESS": Invalid response from http://sub.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/CAh2KFOQD_O3S3ND6o94gp8wpfdTvw2khHEScIf5VLU: 500

  Domain: example.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: "IP-ADRESS": Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/zLMmc9qC-YkhaGD4eAsvzQFhQmjxzXC0MQVV_iNimRA: 500

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary nginx configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure the listed domains point to this nginx server and that it is accessible from the internet.
```

If you know anything I would be delighted!

Greetings.

I didn't try much because I don't understand the error completely.